# Django-Registration: How to prevent logged in user from registering?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I've just started to use django-registration.  I have two questions:

1. How do you prevent a logged in user from going to the register page?
2. How do you automatically sign in a user after activation?

I prefer not changing any code in the app itself.

For question 2, I've already read the docs where it says to  write "a function which listens for the appropriate signal; your function should set the backend attribute of the user to the correct authentication backend, and then call django.contrib.auth.login() to log the user in."  I don't know django well enough to understand what this means or how to implement this.  Could you guys help/point me in the right direction?

Edit:

Tried doing some signals, does not yet work, not sure what's wrong:

```
def loginActivationCallback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print user
    print "registered"

user_registered.connect(loginActivationCallback)
```

Also because I'm using Django 1.5, I didn't do pip install django-registration(does not fully support 1.5), but instead copied the registration folder into my project. Not sure if this affects the signals.

Answer (score 3):

Simply what you can do is check in your register view

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
     #redirect user to the profile page 
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

Comment: I prefer not changing django-registration since it's a 3rd party app

Comment: you can access request.user across the website   apply it wharever you want

Comment: the views are in the 3rd party app so those are the ones being called, not sure what you mean by accessing the request.user from those views without accessing the 3rd party's code

Answer (score 0):

```
from registration.signals import user_activated

def login_user(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' 
    login(request,user)
user_activated.connect(login_user)
```

Comment: I prefer not changing django-registration since it's a 3rd party app

Comment: not sure quite what you mean, could you please be more specific? code of django-registration app is here: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration

Comment: The code for django-registration is linked above.  I simply installed the app, supplied the correct templates, and the urls and views of django-registration handled everything else.

Comment: I was debugging with the django debug toolbar and I noticed that the user_activated/user_registered signals were simply not firing.  Perhaps it won't work unless I pip install the package? But the pip version doesn't work with django 1.5 custom user models.  Perhaps I can't use this 3rd party app?

Comment: You mean you just copy the folder django-registration? If that's what you mean even though your not pip install the app you can use that third-party app. Just simply get the correct path of that folder

Comment: Maybe from project_name.registration.signals import user_activated. I don't know the structure of your project

Comment: I am importing from project_name.registration.singals, but see http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/faq.html#troubleshooting.  Does this mean I can't use signals?

Comment: The documentation is just telling about the possible issue if you didn't install it directly (pip). You can use that signal if you're good in debugging, it will be easy for you to access that folder. Have you try to put it outside the app?

Comment: hmm... not that familiar with django to fully debug this situation.  I guess I'll have to just make my own registration app then.