# How can I prevent a logged in user from accessing a 'Log In' or 'Sign Up' page in Django version 1.9?

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Python.

My problem is that I want to restrict users who are already logged in from being able to visit the log in and sign up pages.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is something like the @login_required decorator, that will allow access to these pages for users who are **not** logged in.

So far, I have

- Looked at other SO questions such as [Django-Registration: How to prevent logged in user from registering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263102/django-registration-how-to-prevent-logged-in-user-from-registering), however I've tried the solution here, and it does not work for me.
- I've searched through the Django Documentation, Django Girls and other websites that offer tutorials for learning Django.

Here's my views.py for the log in:

```
def login_view(request): # Login View to begin user session
print(request.user.is_authenticated())
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserLogInForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print(request.user.is_authenticated())
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = UserLogInForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
else:
    form = UserLogInForm()
return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

and the sign up:

```
class signup_view(View):
    form_class = UserSignUpForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'
    # Blank form is requested
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
        # Form is filled in and posted to DB - Process the Data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Further checks before committing object to the DB
            # Cleaned Data
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,
                                            last_name=last_name,
                                            email=email,
                                            username=username,
                                            password=password
             )
             user.set_password(password)
             user.save()

             user = authenticate(email=email, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

If anybody knows any solutions then that would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: You could redirect to your site's home page instead of preventing access entirely. I think from a user's perspective this would be more intuitive.

Comment: @SaketMehta It's never intuitive to end up where you didn't intend to go. At least register a message informing the user.

Comment: @Melvyn That is true, I agree.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using a class-based view, you can use the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) and in the check method test that the user is anonymous:

```
class signup_view(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    ...
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_anonymous()
```

You can do a similar thing for the other view using the `@user_passes_test` decorator.

Comment: The @user_passes_test decorator works for the login_view, but I can't get the UserPassesTestMixin (test_func) to redirect to the desired page; any idea how I can choose the URL of where I want the page to redirect to?

Comment: You need to define `login_url` at class level, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.login_url).

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can add a middleware something like this :
    your_app/middlewares/user_restriction_middleware.py

and that files be like:

```
class UserRestrictionMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request_path = request.path_info
            if request_path.startswith('/login/') or request_path.startswith('/register/')  :
                return HttpResponseRedirect('.... to whereever you want...')
```

add this to your settings.py's MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES like :
    'your_app.middlewares.user_restriction_middleware.UserRestrictionMiddleware',

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before the POST request form .

```
class login(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('app_name_space_name:your_url_name_to_send_authenticated_user_to')
#Your codes here
```